# Can’t configure a refresh schedule for my Power BI dashboard

Tags: powerbi, dashboard

I have a sql database that i have connected to my dashboard but for some reason I have the schedule refresh disabled. I have tried different things but nothing works.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6amXt.png)

I have tried to enable it from the settings but couldn’t find anything related to scheduled refresh.

Comment: Check under "Data source credentials" - ensure there are no issues/errors there. Is your SQL in the cloud or on prem? If on prem, you will need a gateway....

Comment: Check the Gateway and cloud connections and Data source credentials drop downs.